# How to consume or redirect websocket API data?

Tags: python, c#, websocket

I have access to a third party Python SDK that allows me to subscribe to live stock market data.

Ex. client.subscribe(stock_symbols = stock_symbols)

The above call prints live stock prices using a callback function that is passed to client object.
def on_message(message):
print(message)

When I execute client.subscribe(stock_symbols = stock_symbols) in my python script or interactive python environment, I am able to see live prices of stocks displayed continuously without returning to the prompt till I close the window. [client.subscribe documentation was in a file named Websocket.MD, so I assume it is using websockets for continuous data flow]

Now, I would like to send this streaming data to a C#.NET client application that is running on the same machine as my python script.

What is the best way to achieve this? I tried using websockets library of Python to send data. But it supports only async and await co-routine model. I am not able to send the message from inside on_message function using this API as on_message signature cannot be changed to support async-await co-routine.

I tried to call my python script directly from my C#
console application by launching a child process with script name and other required arguments.
However, I am not able to receive continuous streaming data from Python script even after setting RedirectStandardOutput of processStartInfo object to true. It hangs for a while and displays live stock prices of symbols once and becomes idle. The console then has to be closed.

Summary: Directly running python.py script or the  client.subscribe(stock_symbols = stock_symbols) yields desired results in the console window (continuous real time streaming quotes without returning   user to prompt). But I am unable to send it to C# application. Any advice or   input is appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried ? What is the problem ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: itération-122442: I tried to redirect the output of the call 
    client.subscribe(stock_symbols = stock_symbols)
to my C# console. But as the client.subscribe method call keeps printing the live feed of stock prices, it is not able to continuously send and print it on my C# console window.